# Get file name + path of images in folder - PHP

Tags: php, image, path, filenames

My script is pointing to a folder that stores images.

I would like to retrieve the file name and path name of the images so that my images get loaded when called (see html/php code below).

I have tried the following but i am getting an error:

```
Failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

On this line of code `$page = file_get_contents($fileinfo->getPathname());`

**PHP**

```
public function action_mybook($page = '') {

    FB::log($this->request->param('id1'));
    $this->template->content = View :: factory('mybook/default');
    // give me a list of all files in folder images/mybook_images
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator('images/mybook/');
    $this->template->content->pages = array('.$dir.');
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
            $pages[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
            $page = file_get_contents($fileinfo->getPathname());
        }
    }
  }
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<div id="book">
        <!-- Next button -->
        <div ignore="1" class="next-button"></div>
        <!-- Previous button -->
        <div ignore="1" class="previous-button"></div>
        <?php
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            echo '<div><img src="'.$page.'" /></div>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

If I comment out the line `$page = file_get_contents($fileinfo->getPathname());` and get no errors and the div for the image is created, but it says 'failed to load given url'

Loading the image manually using `echo '<img src="myimage.png">' it displays the image`

Comment: it seems that your image have the permission issue.

Comment: Are you really want to read image code to this variable? `$page = file_get_contents($fileinfo->getPathname());` You only need a path to the file, just $fileinfo->getPathname()

Answer (score 1):

## Possible problem

Your **directory separator**.

I try executate your code and get the same code. Whhy? Because the `/`. In windows is `\`. The return URL is invalid:

```
images/mybook\arrows.png
```

The correctly is:

```
images\mybook\arrows.png

or images/mybook/arrows.png (linux... in windows works too)
```

So, you need to use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant of PHP, this solve your problem. See below:

**UPDATE**

I just add the `$page` to end of the URL in `DirectoryIterator`.

```
public function action_mybook($page = '') {

  FB::log($this->request->param('id1'));
  $this->template->content = View :: factory('mybook/default');

  $dir = new DirectoryIterator('images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'mybook' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $page);
  $this->template->content->pages = array('.$dir.');

  foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {

    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
      $pages[] = $fileinfo->getPathname();
    }

  }

}
```

---

I hope this help.

And sorry for my english.

Comment: i haved tried loading the image manually just using echo '<img src="myimage.png">' and it works fine?

Comment: @KarinaMcGourty You try using the full path/url? Like that: `<img src="yoursite.com/images/mybook/myimage.png" alt="myimage">`. I mean, try if a exiting image of `image/mybook`, not other.

Comment: @KarinaMcGourty Anyway, set the permissions of this folder: `755`, and try again (manually and automatically).

Comment: @KarinaMcGourty What return of `echo $fileinfo->getPathname());`. Try put this code and see the result (if get the correctly path or none)

Comment: When i add that i am getting a long list of files/folders which are inside that main image folder, something like: karina/images/mybook\arrows.pngkarina/images/mybook\1karina/images/mybook\2karina/images/mybook\3........

Comment: @KarinaMcGourty and this ` \ ` was incorrectly. The url need be `karina/images/mybook/arrows.png`. If you put that (`karina/images/mybook/arrows.png`) in your `<img src=`, it's loaded without problems?

Comment: Why would they be the wrong way? In my path to directory i have it set like: ('karina/images/mybook/')

Comment: @KarinaMcGourty let's talk about that in chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45817/discussion-between-patrick-maciel-p4dev-and-karina-mcgourty)

Answer (score 0):

Change permissions on files in directory on 777, and try again

Comment: Bad idea, especially for upload dirs.

Comment: It`s only for debug. If script will work ok, then problem in rights.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment this line:

```
$page = file_get_contents($fileinfo->getPathname());
```

i have no any idea, that you need to read image file to variable.

Check your full image path, try this:

```
$pages[] = 'images/mybook/'.$fileinfo->getFilename();
```

or

```
$pages[] = '/images/mybook/'.$fileinfo->getFilename();
```

relate to your project path.

Comment: When i comment this line out i get no errors, it creates the div for the image but it says 'failed to load the given url'

Comment: Try this: `$pages[] = 'images/mybook/'.$fileinfo->getFilename()` or `$pages[] = '/images/mybook/'.$fileinfo->getFilename()` relate to your project path.

Comment: No joy! It is still just displaying <div><img src=".$dir."></div> An on hover it just says 'Failed to load the given url'

Answer (score -1):

Try to give the permission to your image, you can give the permission using [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) :

```
chmod($fileinfo->getPathname(),0777);//add this line in your code
$page = file_get_contents($fileinfo->getPathname());
```

Note: $fileinfo->getPathname() should return the image path.

Comment: If php can't read the file, it's not very likely it can change the permissions...

Comment: At first: if he have no privileges to read this file - he have no privileges to set chmod too. At second, if you're look to author's code - he dosn't needed to invoke file_get_contents.

Comment: @BaBL86 i dont think that if you don't have permission to read the file than you can not give the permission to the file.the permission can be change using chmod.

Comment: @jeroen i assume it to be on the basis of the error she is occurred.

Comment: You should check the manual: `The mode can be changed only by user who owns the file on most systems. `. If the php user owned the file system (or just the file...), it would just open the file without any problems.